# How to access Apache Basic Authentication user in Flask

Tags: apache, flask

I'm developing a web page using Flask, on an Apache server where the Server is enforcing basic authentication. That is, a user accessing a page on the server is presented with a login screen by Apache, and the login credentials checked prior to passing the request to my page.

The question is whether, and how, I can access the user name from my flask/python code. When using PHP instead of flask/python, on the same server, it is straightforward: The username is a available as a $_SERVER variable (available twice it seems, as the value for keys PHP_AUTH_USER, and also AUTHENTICATE_CN).   I'm guessing/hoping that Apache would similarly make the authenticated username available to flask (perhaps through WSGI somehow), but I can't find it.

I've tried displaying all the key/value pairs in request.headers, but the username isn't there. Is there somewhere else I should look?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I eventually found it, it's available as:

```
request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')
```

Not knowing this wasn't my only problem however, in case
it's useful for anyone, here's the story:

Firstly I tried to find out if WSGI was passing the authentication
info through to flask. This answer to a different question was very
helpful (it shows you how to see everything WSGI is providing before
it gets to flask):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1151129/1956954

When I list the WSGI info as per that answer, it didn't have the
user information. But that turned out to be because the setup for
apache basic authentication in the relevant sites-enabled apache
config file was configured for the document root (a htdocs folder).
Since I'm using WSGI to redirect the relevant requests to a folder
outside of the document route, I didn't actually have authentication
turned on for my page.  (And I didn't notice that because I had accessed
some pages under htdocs, been forced to authenticate, and assumed that
I wasn't being asked to authenticate when I went to my flask pages
because the authentication had been cached).
Creating another  section in the relevant apache sites-enabled
file setting up authentication for my flask directories enabled authentication

Answer (score 18):

You can find authentication information in Flask from the `request` object.

```
from flask import request

def my_view():
    auth = request.authentication
    username = auth.username
    password = auth.password
    ...
```

Note however that if you're using apache **mod_wsgi**, you'll need to turn on the `WSGIPassAuthorization` directive in your virtualhost config. Otherwise apache will consume the authentication header and won't pass it to the WSGI layers.

```
<virtualhost *:443>
    ...

    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    ...
</virtualhost>
```

more info [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPassAuthorization).

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. Although apache setting is `WSGIPassAuthorization On` (No equal sign).

Comment: Tried in both Python 2 and 3 and I got `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'authentication'`